# Derivative of a Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a question about when we compute the derivative of a series.

If the original series converges inside a region $R$, must its derivative also converge on the same region $R$?

Answer (score 1):

If a function can be expressed by a power series converging pointwise in some interval to the function f, then f is analytic in this region, thus is infinitely many often differentiable in R. This implies that the derivations are continous, hence the derivated power series converge pointwise to the corresponding derivates. You must be careful at the bounds of R. In this case, Abels limit theorem often helps.

Comment: If the tag of the question is complex-analysis then why use R in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

*Extracted from: Basic Complex Analysis. 3rd ed. Marsden, Hoffman. Page 207.*

**Differentiation of Power Series:** Let

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

be the analytic function defined on the inside of the circle of convergence of the given power series. Then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_n(z-z_0)^{n-1}$, and this series has the same circle of convergence as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$. Furthermore, the coefficients $a_n$ are given by $a_n=f^{(n)}(z_0)/n!$.